# When 'inline' must be specified explicitly to a definition of namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces, inline

from C++ primer 5th ed. chapter 18: inline namespaces:

An inline namespace is a new feature of namespace added by the new standard , it allows to use the member names of that namespace in the enclosing scope without the need to fully-qualify them. e.g:

```
inline namespace n{
    int x = 9;
}

namespace n{ // implicitly inline
    int y = x;
}

int z = x;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    std::cout << x << ' ' << y << ' ' << z << '\n';

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

- Until here it is OK. What makes me wander is: If I have a namespace that is defined as a dis-contiguous namespace (from several parts, each part in its relevant header/source like `std`). And I want to define my namespace as `inline` thus should each header adds to this namespace defines it `inline` too?

  ```
  // foo.h
  inline namespace ns{
      void foo();
  }

  // foo.cpp
  #include <iostream>
  #include "foo.h"

  void ns::foo(){
      std::cout << "ns::foo()\n";
  }

  // bar.h

  namespace ns{
      void bar();
  }

  // bar.cpp
  #include <iostream>
  #include "bar.h"

  void ns::bar(){
      std::cout << "ns::bar()\n";
  }

  // main.cpp

  #include <iostream>
  #include "foo.h" // defines ns as inline
  #include "bar.h" // opens ns. ns is implicitly inline

  // #include "bar.h" // defines ns as non-inline
  // #include "foo.h" // opens ns. tries to define ns as inline. Error



  int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

      foo(); // ok
      bar(); // ok

      std::cout << '\n';
  }


      std::cout << '\n';
  }
  ```
- The code works fine but it fails to work if I reverse the inclusion of headers `foo.h` and `bar.h`; because if I include `bar.h` first, it defines `ns` as non-inline then including `foo.h` will define it as `inline`, this header Opens the namespace. The compiler fails because `inline` must be specified to first definition of the namespace so `bar.h` needs to define it as `inline` too. So I always need to include 'foo.h' first. Thus only 'foo.h' defines it inline and other header define it as non-inline. But it is not always the case that we need to use 'foo.h' after all defining it `inline` in a single part makes the code inconsistent. Why should I include a header that I don't need its names? After all thinking that it is inline makes me and clients of my library trying to uses names from it without qualifying it thinking it is defined `inline`.
- Is `inline` necessary to all the definitions of a dis-contiguous namespace residing in multiple header/source files if one of them specified it?

Should each header define the same namespace as `inline`?

Comment: Haven’t you answered your own question here?